# Postgres PSQL on Windows do not connect (authentication failed) for a user with uppercases

Tags: postgresql, windows, psql, uppercase

I have a strange behavior with psql on Windows. Let's describe :
on a Postgres server under linux, a user has been created (by error) with uppercases. The connection works on server command line, but not with psql on a Windows machine.

On the Postgres server, on command line, the connection works fine :

```
psql -U myUSER -W -d mydb
mydb#
```

But, if I do the same on a Win11 with psql installed, I can't connect :

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin"\psql -qAt -F '' -h myPGserver -U myUSER -W -d mydb -p 5432
psql: error: connection to server at "myPGserver" (192.xxx.xx.xx), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myUSER"
```

I'm, of course, absolutely sure that I give the right password, like on the linux command line. And the PC is allowed in pg_hba, or this would not be the same error.
I'm lost ... Any brilliant idea ?
Thanks

Comment: 1) To be clear in the Windows case you are connecting to the Postgres server running on the Linux machine, correct? 2) What versions of `psql` on Linux and WIndows? **Add to question text**. 3) What is the line in `pg_hba.conf` that applies?

Comment: What is the error as reported in the server's log file?  It should include more info than the client is given.  The message maybe multiple lines long.

Comment: Why are you using `-W`?  You shouldn't use it unless there is a reason to, and if there is a reason then you should tell us what it is.  Its use might be masking the real problem.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, yes : Windows client (16.1) to linux server (13.6). I have not currently access to pg_hba. I asked to someone locally what is configured, I tell you asap

Comment: @jjanes , I used -W or PGPASSWORD, this make no difference for this problem. I can't access to server's log for the moment, I tell you asap too.